# ¿Como seleccionar varios elementos cuya ID contenga una palabra

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola con javascript estoy haciendo una función en la que quiero ocultar varios elementos, el problema esta en que si utilizo getElementById solo podré seleccionar un solo elemento, y lo que quisiera es ocultar varios que tengan un ID parecido; ejemplo, 'checkbox1', 'checkbox2'

funcion Javascript:

```
function activarcheck(){
        var check = document.getElementById("checkbox");
        if(check.style.display=== "none"){
            check.style.display="block";
        }else{
            check.style.display="none";
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<td>
   <div id="checkbox1"class="container oculto">
       <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" disabled>
   </div>
</td>
 <td>
    <div id="checkbox2" class="container oculto">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: y si les pones una clase a los items que quieres ocultar? puedes usar tambien getElementsByClassName()

Comment: puedes hacer algo como  `document.querySelectorAll("input[id*='checkbox']");` para seleccionar aquellos input cuyo id empieza por checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En lugar de seleccionar por id, puedes seleccionar por clase usando gelElementsByClassName asi:

```js
function activarcheck(){
    var checks = document.getElementsByClassName("oculto");
    for(var i=0; i<checks.length; i++) {
        if(checks[i].style.display=== "none"){
            checks[i].style.display="block";
        }else{
            checks[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<td>
   <div id="checkbox1"class="container oculto">
       <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" disabled>
   </div>
</td>
 <td>
    <div id="checkbox2" class="container oculto">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">
   </div>
</td>
<input type="button" onclick="activarcheck();" value="Esconder"/>
```

Comment: Me funciono muy bien tu solución, gracias!